# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm' when passing sql function as a default parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm aware that this same error has been asked about before, but in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297403/pyspark-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-jvm) and [this other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552309/withcolumn-with-udf-yields-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute?rq=1), the errors are caused by using `pyspark.sql` functions in a `udf`. This is not what I am doing.

The offending code is the following function definition (if I remove the default parameter my code runs and passes all tests).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def apply_filter(df, group=F.lit(True)):
    filtered_df = df.filter(group)
```

I am mainly looking for the reason that this code produces the same error that is found in the other examples.

Edit:

I cannot share the original code due to work, but if you run the previous code with `spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster <filename>` the following error is produced.

```
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Fri Mar 09 16:01:45 +0000 2018
LogLength:343
Log Contents:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 3, in <module>
    def apply_filter(df, group=F.lit(True)):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1520603520946_0005/container_1520603520946_0005_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 40, in _
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
End of LogType:stdout
```

Interestingly enough, the error doesn't persist if it is ran locally.

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace and how you are using the `apply_filter` function please?

Comment: That isn't that relevant to the question, because the errors are caused from just defining the function.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the spark context cannot be instantiated. When you use a pyspark sql function within a `UDF` you're trying to instantiate a spark context within it which is not allowed.

There can be several reason why the spark context cannot be instantiated

- bad spark configuration
- conflicting node configurations
- deploying a jar that is not in adequation with the cluster configurations
- ...